# Проблема с position().left в jQuery

Tags: jquery

position().left возвращает неправильное значение для каждого элемента кроме первого: к примеру 309 вместо 310 и с каждым разом разница растет 1, 2, 5?
как быть?
Когда в консоле firebug набираю тоже самое то расчет идет нормально.

```
$('#nav > li .dropdown').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            width = 0,
            positionRight = 0,
            props = {'position': 'absolute', 'visibility': 'hidden', 'display': 'block'},
            parent = $this.parent(),
            position = parent.position(),
            parentWidth = parent.outerWidth(true),
            positionLeft = position.left;

    jQuery.swap(this, props, function(){
        $this.children('ul').each(function(){
            width += $(this).outerWidth();
        });
    });
    if (width > 0){
        positionRight = 980 - positionLeft - parentWidth + 4;

        if (positionLeft < 600){
            positionLeft = positionLeft;
            if ((positionRight + parentWidth) > width){
                $this.css('left', positionLeft);
            } else {
                $this.css('right', 0);
            }
        } else {
            if ((positionLeft + parentWidth - 200) > width){
                $this.css('right', positionRight);
            } else {
                if (width < 780){
                    $this.css('left', 200);
                } else {
                    $this.css('right', 0);
                }
            }
        }
        $this.css('width', width+1);
    }
});
```